# Difference between quoted/unquoted CMD when docker run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```sh
$ docker run archlinux echo hello
hello
# this yields hello, while
$ docker run archlinux "echo hello"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo hello\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

What's the difference here? Why doesn't the second one work? And I did a further experiment creating a Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh -c"] is incorrect, don't know why
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Building it as `my-archlinux`:

```sh
$ docker run my-archlinux echo hello

# this yields an empty line, so I think hello is not passed to /bin/sh -c
$ docker run my-archlinux "echo hello"
hello
```

I specified entrypoint as `/bin/sh -c` which is the same as docker default, but why the outcome differs?

Comment: Take out the `docker run` part: what's the difference, in your shell, between running `echo hello` and `"echo hello"`?  `/bin/sh -c echo hello` vs. `/bin/sh -c "echo hello"` vs. `"/bin/sh -c" "echo hello"`?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express clearly, result of `docker run archlinux echo hello` is `hello`, but result of `docker run my-archlinux echo hello` is an empty line. Isn't this odd?

Comment: The `ENTRYPOINT` from your Dockerfile gets combined with the command from the `docker run` command.  What happens, outside of Docker, when you run `"/bin/sh" "-c" "echo" "hello"`?  (Compared with `... "echo hello"`?)  Do you understand why?

Comment: I think I understand what you explain, but I think your explanation is irrelevant to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a low level, all Un*x commands are actually executed as a sequence of words.  The shell is responsible for breaking things up into words, and quoting affects how that happens.

```sh
# Both run a command "echo" with a parameter "hello" -- two words
echo hello
"echo" "hello"

# Runs a single command "echo hello" with no parameters -- just one word
"echo hello"
```

In your first example, this processing happens in your local shell, before you run `docker run`.  So Docker runs the same commands inside your container:

```sh
# Starts the container with two arguments ["echo", "hello"]
docker run archlinux echo hello

# Starts the container with one argument ["echo hello"]
docker run archlinux "echo hello"
```

In the Dockerfile syntax you can specify the words explicitly using the JSON-array syntax.

```sh
# The entrypoint is a single word; looks for a file named
# "sh -c", including the space and hyphen in the filename
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh -c"]

# The entrypoint is two words; looks for a file named "sh"
# and passes it an argument "-c"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Finally, the `sh -c` option takes a *single word*, splits it using the shell's normal rules, and runs it.  Again, this is true whether Docker is involved or not.

```sh
# Shell processes "echo hello" and produces two words "echo hello"
# and then runs ["echo", "hello"]
sh -c "echo hello"

# Shell processes "echo", produces one word, and executes it; extra
# "hello" argument is ignored
sh -c "echo" "hello"

# The extra words would be positional parameters starting with $0
# so this prints "world"
sh -c 'echo $1' hello world
```

If you provide both an `ENTRYPOINT` (or `docker run --entrypoint`) and a `CMD` (or `docker run ... some command`), Docker takes the two sets of *words* and combines them together to be the single main container process.  In the Dockerfile syntax you can specify either or both as a bare string, which Docker will wrap in `sh -c` for you.

```sh
 # I'd recommend this for simplicity and clarity
 CMD ["echo", "hello"]

 # Docker turns this into `sh -c "echo hello"`
 CMD echo hello
```

The default `ENTRYPOINT` is no words; setting it to `sh -c` will force callers to condense the command into a single word, which can be awkward.

```sh
 # You need to say explicitly if you do this
 ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
 CMD ["echo hello"] # explicitly one word

 # Since Docker provides sh -c wrapping too, this produces
 #    /bin/sh -c sh -c echo hello
 # and "sh -c" ignores words past the first, so this just
 # runs "sh" with no options
 ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
 CMD echo hello
```

I would suggest avoiding `ENTRYPOINT` in most cases.  There are a couple of useful debugging commands you can run

```sh
# Get a debugging shell in the image I just built
docker run --rm -it my-archlinux bash

# Is my application actually there?
docker run --rm my-archlinux ls -lrt /app
```

and setting something like `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]` (or, I see in other SO questions, `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`) breaks these very common use cases.

Comment: What an excellent explanation! Thx! But the result of `sh -c 'echo $1' hello` is still an empty line?

Comment: That should run `echo $1` with `hello` as the first positional argument; so `echo hello`; so prints "hello".

Comment: I ran it however hello is not printed, tested on macOS and linux.

Comment: ...right, the positional parameters for `sh -c` start with `$0`; `sh -c 'echo $1' hello world` prints `world`.  I'll update the relevant example.

Answer (score 0):

How the `docker run --help` says:

> Usage:    docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

So after the image name(or hash), it expects command and its arguments. Trying to pass the string, like "echo hello" won't be interpreted correctly.

Actually, [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) has two forms:

> ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form, preferred)
>
> ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2 (shell form)

So, `/bin/sh` is an "executable", while everything else should be treated as params.

> this yields an empty line, so I think hello is not passed to /bin/sh
>   -c

Yes, your assumption is correct. The command `/bin/sh -c echo hello` will not print "hello", because the only `echo` will be run, while `/bin/sh -c "echo hello"` will be interpreted as a full command and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: But why in my-archlinux case, result of unquoted echo hello is different compared to archlinux case? Shouldn't `echo` treated as command, and `hello` as arg?

Answer (score 0):

From the archlinux [Dockerfile](https://github.com/archlinux/archlinux-docker/blob/b285a662b4fb81b8614f8705d7ddd7681b8d530b/Dockerfile) we can see that it only specified `CMD` to `["/usr/bin/bash"]` but no `ENTRYPOINT`. So when this image runs without appended arguments, `/usr/bin/bash` is executed. However, if we do:

```sh
$ docker run archlinux echo hello
```

from ENTRYPOINT [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), we know that

> CMD will be overridden when running the container with alternative arguments.

What this `docker run` command actually do under the hood is `echo hello`, **no `/bin/sh -c` thing!** What quoted `echo hello` does is `"echo hello"`, which is of course command not found.

In my-archlinux case, the Dockerfile specified `ENTRYPOINT` (this operation resets `CMD` to empty so run my-archlinux without appending any args yields `/bin/sh: -c: option requires an argument`).

Command

```sh
$ docker run my-archlinux echo hello
```

is executed as

```sh
/bin/sh -c echo hello
```

this yields an empty line apparently.

Command

```sh
$ docker run my-archlinux "echo hello"
```

is executed as

```sh
/bin/sh -c "echo hello"
```

which yields hello.

The key point here is actually that archlinux image doesn't specified `ENTRYPOINT` while my-archlinux Dockerfile does.

Many thanks to @funnydman and @Maze, correct me if I'm wrong.